# Jenkinsfile to automatically deploy to EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, amazon-eks

How do I pass my aws credentials when I am running a Jenkinsjob
taking this as an example https://github.com/PaulMaddox/amazon-eks-kubectl

```
$ docker run -v ~/.aws:/home/kubectl/.aws -e CLUSTER=demo    maddox/kubectl get services
```

The above works on my laptop , but I want to pass aws credentials on the file.I have aws configured in my Jenkins-->credentials .I also have a bitbucket repo which contains a Jenkinsfile and a yam file for "service" and "deployment"

the way I do it now is run the kubectl create -f filename.yaml and it deploys to eks .. just want to do the same thing but automate it with a Jenkinsfile , suggestions on how to do it either with kubectl or with helm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Jenkinsfile you should include similar section:

```
 stage('Deploy on Dev') {
    node('master'){
        withEnv(["KUBECONFIG=${JENKINS_HOME}/.kube/dev-config","IMAGE=${ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${ECR_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGETAG}"]){
            sh "sed -i 's|IMAGE|${IMAGE}|g' k8s/deployment.yaml"
            sh "sed -i 's|ACCOUNT|${ACCOUNT}|g' k8s/service.yaml"
            sh "sed -i 's|ENVIRONMENT|dev|g' k8s/*.yaml"
            sh "sed -i 's|BUILD_NUMBER|01|g' k8s/*.yaml"
            sh "kubectl apply -f k8s"
            DEPLOYMENT = sh (
                script: 'cat k8s/deployment.yaml | yq -r .metadata.name',
                returnStdout: true
            ).trim()
            echo "Creating k8s resources..."
            sleep 180
            DESIRED= sh (
                script: "kubectl get deployment/$DEPLOYMENT | awk '{print \$2}' | grep -v DESIRED",
                returnStdout: true
            ).trim()
            CURRENT= sh (
                script: "kubectl get deployment/$DEPLOYMENT | awk '{print \$3}' | grep -v CURRENT",
                returnStdout: true
            ).trim()
            if (DESIRED.equals(CURRENT)) {
                currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
                return
            } else {
                error("Deployment Unsuccessful.")
                currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                return
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

which will be responsible for automating deployment proccess.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Do I need any thing specific plugin for kubernetes/kubectl ?

Comment: I assume that when you said "kubectl create -f filename.yaml " that you had already had kubectl plugin installed on your environment. If not install it following this instruction: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-kubectl.html and setup kubeconfig file https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html

Comment: I have to be more clear in my comments  , I meant Jenkins plugin .I did install Kubernetes cli plugin

Comment: I followed this blog and able to do some configs but not all https://illya-chekrygin.com/2017/08/26/configuring-certificates-for-jenkins-kubernetes-plugin-0-12/